# On React Native, when applying code push more than a time, Image assets not displaying on Android

Tags: android, react-native

Anyone had experienced similar issue with me? When I apply code push for the first time, no problem, but when I apply code push more than a time, 2 times or 3 times, I cannot see any image assets on APP. If I clear data and cache and open APP again and install code push, it shows all images assets properly since it is the first code push.

Comment: Hi, Did you find the solution? I am also facing the same.

Comment: @jane Did you manage to get it to work? I am also facing the same. Vector icons are not displayed in 2 times onwards

Answer (score 1):

We had same issue with a particular png file and Vector Icon that disappear after codepush update

7.0.1 does NOT help

This helped https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/1350#issuecomment-915972333

But now the issue seems to have come back and after further digging seems to be related to the paths of the images in the original app binary vs the paths of the images related to the codepush bundle/binary

This link is next to zero useful because it fails to explain how to fix the issue lol https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/rn-troubleshooting

Have tried changing the way the image is required but no fix as yet. No idea why icon asset fails to load when others are just fine

If I find anything that helps I'll post back here

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `7.0.2` version. Downgrading to the previous one `7.0.1` works.

Answer (score 0):

Update to version `7.0.4`. Microsoft releases this version to fix specifically the issue that local images won't load on Android after the second CodePush update.

After having updated CodePush to this version, I no longer have this issue anymore. Images in my assets show up again on Android after the second CodePush update.

Release note here: https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/releases/tag/v7.0.4